# Automating C++ unit test runs for WinRT

Tags: unit-testing, visual-c++, mstest, windows-runtime

Since running Metro apps headlessly is still a gray area: [Running a metro app headlessly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179135/running-a-metro-app-headlessly), I've recently decided to add a native unit test project to my Windows Metro app in hopes that I can find a way to run these unit tests in an automated fashion on the build server. Basically, I'm looking for something similar to MSTest.exe - a utility which is great for running tests from batch files and/or scripts.

In fact, I've tried using the new version of MSTest.exe that comes with VS11 on a generated test .dll, but it fails with the error:

"Unable to load the test container 'test.dll' or one of its dependencies... Error details: Could not load file or assembly file://test.dll' or one of its dependencies. The Module was expected to contain an assembly manifest."

Does MSTest.exe work with test containers that contain WinRT code? If not, is there a utility that will do what I want?

---

Edit: I just found out that MSTest does not support running tests on a Metro style app. Found here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253138%28v=vs.110%29.aspx This really is too bad. I'm still hoping there's a utility out there that will work.

Answer (score 3):

After blindly digging through the VS folders, I happened to find a new test runner under:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   11.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe

This utility allows you to execute WinRT unit tests from the command line. It's very similar to MSTest.exe.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation out there for this yet, but at least a help command exists.

Answer (score 1):

If you are executing vstest.console.exe <filename>.dll then your tests do not get executed in appcontainer mode. You need to give <filename>.appx to execute tests in appcontainer mode. More info on how to execute tests for Windows Metro style apps from command line can be found at [Running Unit Tests for Windows Metro style apps from Command Line](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vikramagrawal/archive/2012/05/06/running-unit-tests-for-windows-metro-style-apps-from-command-line.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

There is a documentation about (among other things) running unit tests for Windows Phone:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn168930(v=vs.105).aspx

It describes also the command line way of doing it using vstest.console.exe.

It also gives a comparison of supported features between unit tests for Windows Phone and WinRT.

One important detail is that unit tests for WinRT cannot be run on a device. This is a pity and relevant to question [How to automate non-interactive tests on Microsoft Surface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20349429/how-to-automate-non-interactive-tests-on-microsoft-surface)